# Can't save a workbook after deleting sheets - openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm manipulating a sheet, mainly deleting all the sheets but the one that I need. I will loop through all the sheets, and delete the sheets that is not useful for my task.

After deleting, I tried to save but it throws an error.

```
File "C:\Users\myUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 130, in active
return self._sheets[self._active_sheet_index]
```

Here's my script

```
wb = load_workbook("File.xlsx")

ws1 = wb["Employee Info"]
ws1.freeze_panes = None

ws_active = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Employee Info")

### delete other sheets but Employee Info
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    if sheet.title != 'Employee Info':
        print("removing " + sheet.title)
        wb.remove_sheet(sheet)

print("remaining sheets:")
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    print("    " + sheet.title)

### TODO
### loop through the files in a directory

### TODO
### see if readable by ETL 

print("saving the wb")

wb.save("modified.xlsx")
```

after deleting, I checked the workbook. And it has the sheet that I am looking for. Just not sure though why it is not detecting the remaining 1 sheet.

To add more details, the excel file has 8 sheets, the sheet that I am after is on the 5th sheet.

Comment: Sounds like https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/748/ Please upgrade your version of openpyxl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me this is working with 2.4.2 version:

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

for i in workbook.worksheets:
    if i.title != 'Employee Info':
        workbook.remove_sheet(i)

workbook.save('test2.xlsx')
```

Try it simple to see if its working.
You can also use the `workbook.sheetnames` to see the sheetnames:

```
for sheet in workbook.sheetnames:
    print(sheet)
```

Comment: how many sheets do you have there on test.xlsx? I tried creating a test file with 5 sheets and I encounter the same error

Comment: I have 12 sheets. It works with `workbook.remove_sheet(i)` and with `workbook.remove(i)` like Eric Pratt told. I tried it with openpyxl version 2.4.2 and Python 3.5.1 with Windows 7 and Python 3.6 and Arch Linux

Comment: this was a version issue, this got fixed in 2.4.2. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

wb.remove_sheet() is deprecated from the official [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.html). I can't comment yet, but do you get the same error when using wb.remove()?

Comment: sadly, yes Eric. I still get the same error. tried the del wb[sheet] syntax as well but still the same

Comment: @niccolom.  What version of openpyxl are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.4.1 as seen under the anaconda package

Answer (score 1):

Before saving, you can use as a workaround:

```
wb.active = 0
```

Update to 2.4.2, last change reads:
  **workbook.py Fail gracefully when the active sheet is deleted.**