# Openpyxl not removing sheets from created workbook correctly

Tags: python, openpyxl

So I ran into an issue with `remove_sheet()` with openpxyl that I can't find an answer to. When I run the following code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet("Sheet2")
wb.get_sheet_names()
['Sheet','Sheet2']
wb.remove_sheet('Sheet')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

It doesn't work, even if I try `wb.remove_sheet(0)` or `wb.remove_sheet(1)`, I get the same error. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use `get_sheet_by_name` you will get the following:

> `DeprecationWarning`: Call to deprecated function `get_sheet_by_name` (Use
>   `wb[sheetname]`).

So the solution would be:

```
xlsx = Workbook()
xlsx.create_sheet('other name')
xlsx.remove(xlsx['Sheet'])
xlsx.save('some.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 10):

`remove.sheet()` is given a sheet object, not the name of the sheet!

So for your code you could try

```
wb.remove(wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet))
```

In the same vein, remove_sheet is also not given an index, because it operates on the actual sheet object.

Here's a [good source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216623/cant-save-a-workbook-after-deleting-sheets-openpyxl) of examples (though it isn't the same problem you're facing, it just happens to show how to properly call the remove_sheet method)!

Answer (score 4):

Since the question was posted and answered, the Openpyxl library changed.

You should not use `wb.remove(wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet))` as indicated by [@cosinepenguin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7299505/cosinepenguin) since it is now depreciated ( you will get warnings when trying to use it ) but `wb.remove(wb[sheet])`

Answer (score 3):

In python 3.7

```
 import openpyxl

 wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

 ws = wb.create_sheet("Sheet2")

 n=wb.sheetnames

 #sheetname =>get_sheet_names()

 wb.remove(wb["Sheet"])

 '#or can use' 

 wb.remove(wb[n[1]])
```

**1 is index sheet "sheet"**

you can [visit this link for more info](http://ilearnwithyou.cf/module/python/openpyxl_2.php)